# Classes name through an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var ar = ["blue", "green", "red"],
    x = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV'),
    i,
    colors = {};

colors[ar[0]] = 'blue';
colors[ar[1]] = 'green';
colors[ar[2]] = 'red';

for (i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[x[i].className];
}
```

```css
.one_in,.two_in ,three_in{ width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<div class="blue one_in">
</div><div class="green two_in">
</div><div class="one_in">
</div><div class="red "></div>
```

Why doesnt work when i put multiple class and spaces , if i put white space in the array `["blue" + " ", "green" + " ", "red"+ " "]`, doesnt work how to achieve this ?

when I remove the class from `div` this gonna work again ?

Comment: First thing, missing a *`.`* in front of `three_in` in `.one_in,.two_in ,three_in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result , use below option

```
x[i].style.background = colors[x[i].className.split(' ')[0]];
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rWgPRj

Comment: @Anjali :  I'd added the same answer even before this answer and got downvoted :D

Comment: I am splitting the class names string with space(' ') and getting first class name - className.split(' ')[0]

Answer (score 1):

Because `.className` gives you name of all classes. For example `green two_in` whereas what you want is only `green`. therefore you should add `one_in` as the `id` of that div

```js
var ar = ["blue", "green","white", "red"],
    x = document.querySelectorAll('div'),i,colors = {};

colors[ar[0]] = 'blue';
colors[ar[1]] = 'green';
colors[ar[2]] = 'white';
colors[ar[3]] = 'red';

for (i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[x[i].className];
}
```

```css
#one_in,#two_in,#three_in{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<div class="blue" id="one_in">
</div><div class="green"id="two_in">
</div><div id="one_in">
</div><div class="red" id="three_in">
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't have an id so it was not showing. read the code first

Comment: the white one was third one. red was fourth one. third one didn't have `class="red"`so it was white

Comment: You just editted it... Dont play dumb. You know it wasn't showing.

Comment: I edited to show you that code works. It was not showing before still it was right

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for the wrong values...

`x[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[x[i].className];`

the class names are "red ", "green two_in" and "blue one_in"

You need to match the classnames EXACTLY.

Unlike in jQuery, classNames aren't nicely sorted for you, into an array, they're the raw string you type into the HTML ( which is why even the "red " isn't working ).

I suggest you use jQuery for a quick solution

Alternatively you could do this:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++) {
    classNames = x[i].style.split(" ");
    for (var j = classNames.length; j--;) if (colors[classNames[j]]) {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[classNames[j]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code won't because there is no property with the exact match of your `className` property.

To fix the problem, get the first class name from the class names using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

```js
var ar = ["blue", "green", "red"],
  x = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV'),
  i,
  colors = {};

colors[ar[0]] = 'blue';
colors[ar[1]] = 'green';
colors[ar[2]] = 'red';

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[x[i].className.split(" ")[0]];
}
```

```css
.one_in,
.two_in,
.three_in {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue one_in">
</div>
<div class="green two_in">
</div>
<div class="one_in">
</div>
<div class="red three_in"></div>
```